# Why Identity 2.0 adds a new column in AspNetUserRoles when I extend IdentityUser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have derived a class from IdentityUser, CustomUser.
If I check the database tables, I can see that Identity 2.0 has added a third column to AspNetUserRoles  table, called CustomUser_Id.

It seems a foreign key to my CustomUser table, but AspNetUserRoles  already has UserId column, so it seems redundant.

Why? What I am missing?

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: have you used EF model binding correctly for the new CustomUser. You may need to inherit CandidateUser : IdentityUser<string, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>

Comment: Sorry mean to say CustomUser : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityRole, IdentityUserClaim>. Post your IdentityDbContext code, that has to be inherited correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you've also got `ApplicationUser` hanging around. `IdentityUser` is an abstract class, so the column in `dbo.AspNetUserRoles` is attached to whatever concrete class is used as the `TUser` type for the generic `IdentityDbContext<TUser>`. By default, that's `ApplicationUser`. If you created another subclass of `IdentityUser`, all you've done is create a class with similar properties, but one which is totally disconnected from all the Identity stuff and has its own table, `dbo.CustomUsers` probably, which then requires a separate foreign key to be added on `dbo.AspNetUserRoles` for it.

Long and short, you only get one bite at the user apple. If you want to have different types of users, they need to inherit from your main user implementation (`ApplicationUser` by default), not `IdentityUser`.

Comment: @Chriss Could you please take a look at this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72183250/asp-net-core-identity-added-extra-foreign-key-in-aspnetuserroles