# Third column in AspNetUserRoles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

Similar Problem as in [Why Identity 2.0 adds a new column in AspNetUserRoles when I extend IdentityUser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765815)
My ApplicationUser class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
  public ApplicationUser()
  {
    Address = new Address ();
  }
  public string Firstname{ get; set; }
  public string Lastname{ get; set; }
  public Address Address{ get; set; }
  public bool IsActivated { get; set; }
}
```

And the context:

```
public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
  static DatabaseContext()
  {
    Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
  }

  public DatabaseContext()
    : base(nameOrConnectionString: "Archive")
  {
  }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
}
```

The created columns in table AspNetUserRoles are: UserId, RoleId and IdentityUser_Id. If I assign a role to a user, only UserId and RoleId are filled. If I want to retrieve in which roles a user is, nothing comes back.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there should not be column called IdentityUser_Id in IdentityUserRole table. And I hope you are using entity ramework code first approach.

Try changing your `OnModelCreating` method as below. Currently you have created your `ApplicationUser` table by inheriting from `IdentityUser`. So that, you don't need to model bind for `IdentityUser`.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
}
```

Hope this helps.